# Сумасшедшие constains в android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, constraints

Работаю в Android studio 3.0.1, пришло время закончит проект, у меня много элементов на экране и когда нажимаю infer constrains и начинается полный хаос. Сделать несколько Activity нельзя. Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, добавляя constrains для каждого элемента вручную.